# Package subpath './src/ngtsc/reflection' is not defined by "exports" in /node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/package.json

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am trying to run the ng test with jest and getting this following error

`Package subpath './src/ngtsc/reflection' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/oyf992/source/app-mngt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/package.json`

I am using

`"@angular/core": "^13.0.1",`
`"jest": "27.2.3",`
`"jest-preset-angular": "10.0.1",`

let me know what could be the reason and possible solution.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR**

1. upgrade the following Jest dependencies *at minimum**, and
2. update Jest and Typescript configuration

*Your project may require additional upgrades--mine did. I've found search results related to (1) Angular 13 upgrade + Jest and (2) Jest ESModule support to be most helpful.

```
"@angular-builders/jest": "^13.0.2",
"jest": "^27.4.7",
"jest-preset-angular": "^11.0.1",
"ts-jest": "^27.1.2",
```

---

### Angular 13 and Jest: what changed?

The most disruptive breaking change to Jest in Angular 13 was **ESModule artifacts (`.mjs`)**. Jest runs in the Node which supports CommonJS modules. It has experimental support for ESModules and requires additional configuration to enable it.

Upgrading `jest-preset-angular` resolved the first error (reflection subpath) and uncovered a second error:

```sh
$HOME/$PROJECT/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.mjs:7
    import { getDebugNode, RendererFactory2, ɵstringify, ɵReflectionCapabilities, Directive, Component, Pipe, NgModule, ɵgetInjectableDef, resolveForwardRef, ɵNG_COMP_DEF, ɵRender3NgModuleRef, ApplicationInitStatus, LOCALE_ID, ɵDEFAULT_LOCALE_ID, ɵsetLocaleId, ɵRender3ComponentFactory, ɵcompileComponent, ɵNG_DIR_DEF, ɵcompileDirective, ɵNG_PIPE_DEF, ɵcompilePipe, ɵNG_MOD_DEF, ɵtransitiveScopesFor, ɵpatchComponentDefWithScope, ɵNG_INJ_DEF, ɵcompileNgModuleDefs, NgZone, Compiler, COMPILER_OPTIONS, ɵNgModuleFactory, ModuleWithComponentFactories, InjectionToken, Injector, InjectFlags, ɵresetCompiledComponents, ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible } from '@angular/core';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Next I upgraded `@angular-builders/jest`, `jest`, and `ts-jest`. Changes to your Jest and Typescript configuration may also be needed. In your `tsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.spec.json`, check that it "has `module` [in `compilerOptions`] with value for ESM, e.g. ES2015 or ES2020 etc..." as noted in the [ts-lint migration doc](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/).

Below are the changes I made to my project's Jest configuration, but each project is a little different.

```js
// jest.config.js
const esModules = ['@angular', '@ngrx', 'd3', [...]];
module.exports = {
  // [...]
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'], // ts-jest
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      useESM: true, // ts-jest
    },
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'html', 'js', 'json', 'mjs'], // jest-preset-angular
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1', // ts-jest
  },
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    `<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$|${esModules.join('|')})`, // jest-preset-angular
  ],
}
```

If you're still having issues I've included links to each migration doc below. I'm still working through issues with other packages but hope this sets you on a good path!

### Migration and ESM support docs

- Angular latest upgrade: https://angular.io/guide/update-to-latest-version
- `@angular-builders/jest`: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/MIGRATION.MD
- `jest-preset-angular`: https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/next/guides/angular-13+/
- `ts-jest` ESM support: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/
- Jest ESM support: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules
- If you're still getting `Cannot use import` errors, a helpful comment on a closed GitHub issue: https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/1149#issuecomment-963506942

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which one, but after updating these dependencies I got rid of this error:

```
"@briebug/jest-schematic": "^4.0.0",
"ts-jest": "^27.1.2",
"@angular-builders/jest": "13.0.2",
"@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
"jest": "^27.4.5",
"jest-when": "^3.5.0",
```